# How to create array of given length and same number?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, dynamic-arrays

When using SUMSERIES I need to specify "the array or range containing the coefficients of the power series" but I want to make it so the number of elements is dynamic while the element itself (1) remains the same.
Example:

SUM FROM 0 TO N of x^1,5

```
(cell) Length of series N : 7  -- > SUMSERIES(1,5;0;1;{1,1,1,1,1,1,1})
```

But I should be able to change the seven for a 3 and get --> `SUMSERIES(1,5;0;1;{1,1,1})`

In Java for example you'd declare and instantiate the array --> `int[] arr = new int[N];`

And then fill in a loop --> `for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {arr[i] = 1,5}`

Thanks in advance and sorry if the explanation isn´t clear, it's my first time around hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
=SUMSERIES(1,5;0;1;SEQUENCE(1,[cell],1,0))
```

Comment: This may answer the question. However, code only answers are not as useful as answers that document the code or have an detailed explanation on why this code is the solution to the question.

Comment: Apologies for not explaining the code better.  The sequence function can generate an array of repeated numbers by using 0 as the 4th parameter. I just tried to replace the constructed array using that.

Comment: As per 2023 the syntax seems to be broken. I've published here an updated answer based on this that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76664454/6108874

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SIGN(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A1)))))
```

[image: 0]

---

and then:

```
=INDEX(SUMSERIES(1,5; 0; 1; SIGN(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A1))))))
```

Comment: I have tested it and works just fine but I preferer the solution where I dont need new cells, thanks a lot though!!

Answer (score 0):

In older version of Excel you can get this array using this (**all of them are array formulas**)

- `=INDEX(MUNIT(n),1,0)*0+x` for horizontal array
- `=INDEX(MUNIT(n),0,1)*0+x` for vertical array

Where:

- `n` is dimension of the array
- `x` is value of each item in the array

**How it works:**

`MUNIT` creates an identity matrix of size N

```
+---++---+---+---+---+---+
|   || 1 | 2 | . | . | n |
+---++---+---+---+---+---+
+---++---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 || 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 || 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| . || 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| . || 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| n || 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
+---++---+---+---+---+---+
```

Now we extract one (the first) row/column (`n` is set to `7` here)

- `=INDEX(MUNIT(7),1,0)` for row extraction
- `=INDEX(MUNIT(7),0,1)` for column extraction

And fill it with desired number (desired number here is `9` here)

- `=INDEX(MUNIT(7),1,0)*0+9` for row
- `=INDEX(MUNIT(7),0,1)*0+9` for column

Answer (score 0):

As per 2023, this is the formula that is working to me (adapted from a previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60305735/6108874):

```
=SERIESSUM(x, n, m, a)
```

where for example,

`x = ?` the base of the power,

`n = 1` the exponent,

`m = 1` the exponent step,

`a = SEQUENCE(<rows>, 1, 1, 0)` the array of ones (1) with size `<rows>`.

☝ the `a` is the part the OP is specifically asking for.